# How to remove recursion?

Tags: php, recursion, trace

I am trying to `json_encode` `debug_backtrace` output for the purpose of storing this information in database.

The problem is that sometimes it contains recursion. Something I don't care about. Simply `*RECURSION*` at the point where recursion is detected would be enough.

How do I do that?

Comment: Databases values don't need to be encoded as JSON.

Comment: Well, I need to store this data as part of error report. I don't care about relations or should I say, I don't want to create additional 2 tables just for the backtrace information.

Comment: what happens now? an example would be helpfull. just keep it as short as possible.

Comment: @alex - How can you give such a rule of thumb?!

Comment: @ItayMoav I said they don't *need* to be. They can be, but I find it's rarely the best way to do it.

Comment: The OP has a simple question; how to json_encode a PHP value with recursive references. Don't close this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue myself.  I too resolved it with a function that went through and removed all the recursive references.  Ironic that the function to do so is itself recursive!  This is what I came up with:

```
public static function remove_recursion(&$object, &$stack = array()) {
    if ((is_object($object) || is_array($object)) && $object) {
        if (!in_array($object, $stack, true)) {
            $stack[] = $object;
            foreach ($object as &$subobject) {
                self::remove_recursion($subobject, $stack);
            }
        } else {
            $object = "***RECURSION***";
        }
    }
    return $object;
}
```

For the first call, you don't need to pass in a second argument, that's just there for when it recurs.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the stack parameter should not be passed by reference here as it modifies the stack for all layers of recursion instead of just ones lower down.

Comment: This is not correct. You are doing a depth-first search, which produces the wrong output

Comment: Didn't work for me. I just receive `HTTP/2 500 Internal Server Error`.

Answer (score 0):

serialize would indeed be a good alternative.

Lacking that, there's no other way then to traverse the tree, keep all the arrays and objects and see if they refer to the same value.

For objects its a bit easier, because you can use spl_object_hash.

For arrays, the only way I can think of right now is the following

```
function referToTheSame(&$arr1, &$arr2) {
  // copy
  $tmp = $arr1;

  $arr1 = 'foo';
  $result = ($arr2==='foo');
  $arr1 = $tmp;

  return $result;

}
```

Would love to hear if there's a smarter way.

Oh and since you're only interested in breaking recursion, and not so much *any reference* this wouldn't have to be that expensive. Just keep a stack while you're traversing, so you only have to compare against parents.

**EDIT**

Couldn't help myself. This breaks array references, but not object references. Sure you can figure that one out:

(warning: ugly code)

```
<?php

$structure = array(
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'bar',
);

$structure[] =& $structure;

function traverse($item, &$stack) {

    foreach($item as $key=>&$value) {

        if (is_array($value)) {

            // Checking if this array already appeared in the stack
            foreach($stack as &$array2) {

                // Copy
                $tmp = $array2;
                $array2 = 'foo';
                if ($value==='foo') {
                    $array2 = $tmp;

                    // We need to create another temporary value, to break the 
                    // reference.
                    $newValue = '* INCEPTION *';
                    $value =& $newValue;
                    continue 2; 
                } else {
                    $array2 = $tmp;
                }

            }

            $stack[] =& $value;
            traverse($value, $stack);
            array_pop($stack);

        }

    }

}

$stack = array();
$stack =& $structure;
traverse($structure, $stack);

print_r($structure);

?>
```

Comment: I don't think it has to do with recurring functions. The output of debug_backtrace can still contain circular references through the 'object' and 'args' keys.

Answer (score 0):

Just `serialize`, then `unserialize`. This works for me:

```
$backtrace = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_PROVIDE_OBJECT);
$backtrace = unserialize(serialize($backtrace));
die(json_encode(backtrace));
```